# Google Script for Sheet Auto Sort not triggering

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script that works during testing but it does not trigger on edit. Basically in Column 5 I have a dropdown and want them to sort when changed.

```
// Define the order by which you want to sort
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 5, ascending: true},  // index 1 for category column
{column: 17, ascending: false} // Index 3 for Revenu column
];
// On sheet edit, apply the function multiSortColumns()
function onEdit(e){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19elFArXzf32sSkeyxJ39cSYOVG4PH51px42-ocW3HYI/edit#gid=1695682723");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Deals"); // Get the working sheet name
var range = sheet.getRange("A2:T"); // Get the range of data
range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
}
```

I tried changing the form onEdit to onChange and no luck.

Comment: From `onEdit`, if you are using this function as the simple trigger, I think that `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl` is the reason for your current issue. In this case, please test it as the installable OnEdit trigger. But, please rename `onEdit` to another name like `installedOnEdit` and install the installable OnEdit trigger to the renamed function. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: When I use "getActiveSpreadsheet" I get  the following error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getSheetByName')". That's why I need to use the URL or ID.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the same worsheet you're working on, try changing the definition of `ss`  to:

```
var ss = e.source
```

That should overcome the permissions issue for onEdit. Let me know!